# How to stop AWS EC2 Container Service (Fargate) from running

Tags: amazon-web-services

I had a container service instance i believe running in ECS/EC2. I deleted the EC2 instance and any ECS cluster around 12:30pm yesterday. Now over 24 hours i noticed that the cost of vCPU usage is still going up even though i deleted the EC2 Instance and ECS Cluster under US East 2 (Ohio) region as that what it states on the bill.

But i still see an increase under the following resource  `AWS Fargate - vCPU - US East 2 (Ohio)` when i navigate to the bills area why?

I double checked everywhere under the various regions and i cannot see anything still running or being consumed. I can only see "inactive" Task Definitions.

So how do i prevent from incurring further costs?

Has anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 0):

Whether you are using EC2 or Fargate launch type, you still need a cluster to host your tasks. So if there is no cluster in your account, you should incur no charges. There might be some problem with console UI that is not showing your cluster correctly, it happened to me that I have deleted cluster from console and there was some error which prevented cluster from being completely deleted and I ended up in a weird state where console indicated that the cluster was deleted while it wasn't.
This stuff actually happened to me more than once and not only with ECS so I would always recommend to use CLI to double check your actions.

Run this command

```
aws ecs list-clusters --region us-east-2
```

If the output is not empty then you will need to delete that cluster via CLI

```
aws ecs   delete-cluster --cluster <value> --region us-east-2
```

If the output is empty then there is no cluster running in your Ohio region and those charges were simply delayed a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I ran the first command in your answer, and the result was empty. I ran it for all regions just to be safe and they're all empty. So in my situation when i deleted it from the AWS Console UI it did actually remove it. 

I also checked ElasticBeanstalk and EC2 areas via the CLI tool and no resources are listed there. 

I will check back in few hours and see if the charges do go up but like you said it may have been delayed.